# Return excel cell values where column and row headers match specified values

Tags: python, datatables, openpyxl

I have a table of census tract information, the first column of which contains a unique identifying code for each tract. The table also includes a header describing the contents of the rows in that column (for example, "pop" for "population", "unempl" for "unemployment", etc.).

I would like to select individual cells from specific census tracts for specific attribues and find sums for those tracts and attributes (for example, returning the total population for census tracts XXX, YYY, and ZZZ).

I know I need to reference the cell position where tract and column header line up but am not sure how to access that. I am open, also, to the possibility that there may be a better way to perform this task.

My code if incomplete but here is what I am working with:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Get tracts from user
inputTracts = input("Enter tract number(s): ")

# Create list from tract numbers
inputTracts = inputTracts.split(', ')

# Get number of tracts in the list
numberOfTracts = len(inputTracts)

# Specify headers to look for
searchTerms = ['pop', 'pop60', 'unempl', 'lbrforce', 'hs', 'col', 'pov']

def sum_columns(table):
    total = 0
    tableSum = []

    for cell in range(0, numberOfTracts):
        for tract in inputTracts:
            if cell[0] == tract:
                for cell in table:
                    for term in searchTerms:
                        if cell.value == term:
                            total += # cell position reference here?
                            tableSum.append(total)

    # return the list of totals
    return tableSum
```

Comment: Try using Pandas to read in an excel file.  Pandas is great for this type of work, for example it can evaluate lots of rows and columns at once.  I'm unclear on your code, for example, if cell.value == term, then it is a string, so why try adding that string to a total?

Comment: Thanks, that is an error from a late addition to my code. I knew it wasn't working but wanted to give an example. I can edit it for clarity but will also look more into Pandas, which I am not very familiar with.

Comment: This is all pseudo code. It looks like you should read the openpyxl introduction first.